# Disqus marks blog comments as spam and redacts them, if they are edited too many times

Tags: bug, blog

If you post a comment to the Stack Overflow blog, and then edit it too many times, Disqus will mark the comment as spam and remove it from the blog.

Comment: Is that a bug, though? I thought that was by design. On blogs, editing comments is usually rare. I typically wouldn't edit a comment more than once. :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop: It was a fairly detailed comment.  I'm used to freely editing things on the Stack Exchange network, and I expect a reasonable degree of editing capability in other places.  I could, of course, compose it in a separate editor before posting, but... really?

Comment: These sort of problems plague blogs everywhere.  Because of the actions of bad actors, I'm constantly forced to login and tie what I say anywhere on the internet together.  While I'm marked as spam because I'm trying to be a bit nuanced, the vile posters of the world get to spew their filth unchallenged.  It's all incredibly aggravating.

Comment: Question is, can Stack Exchange control that? Only "fix" might be to find other host for the comments.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Supposedly, [yes](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466244-dealing-with-spam) is within the Discus admin panel, specifically [this](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466242-using-the-blacklist-and-whitelist)

Comment: @Braiam huh, nice find. Well, let's hope SE will do something.